# Set EXTjs button/item text from cookie

Tags: javascript, extjs, cookies

I used EXTjs version 5. Where I have created a Cookie with EXTjs to store the username of the logged user. So the next thing I want to do, is to show the stored username inside a button/item.

The button/item code do's like:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    text: 'The username from the cookie must placed here',
    menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
       items: [
           {text: 'Uitloggen', handler: 'onLogoutClick' }
       ]
    })
}]
```

Comment: Once the view is rendered (afterrender), call `setText` on the button by passing the cookie value

Comment: so add the value to the `viewModel` and use `bind` in your button to bind that value.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can anyone post some example code or link to an example or tutorial for me? That makes it more clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments I give you an example with viewmodel and cookie.

If you want to use ViewModel and Cookies you need formulas to set the data.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lnn

```
Ext.define("MyViewModel", {
    extend: "Ext.app.ViewModel",

    alias: "viewmodel.myviewmodel",

    data: {
        _username: null
    },

    formulas: {
        username: {
            bind: "{_username}",

            get: function(val) {
                if (Ext.isEmpty(val))
                    val = Ext.util.Cookies.get("myUsername");
                return val;
            },

            set: function(val) {
                Ext.util.Cookies.set("myUsername", val);
                this.set("_username", val);
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.create("Ext.Viewport", {
    viewModel: "myviewmodel",
    items: [{
        xtype: "textfield",
        fieldLabel: "Username",
        bind: "{username}"
    }, {
        xtype: 'splitbutton',
        bind: "{username}",
        //text: 'The username from the cookie must placed here',
        menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
            items: [{
                text: 'Uitloggen',
                handler: 'onLogoutClick'
            }]
        })
    }]
});
```